# forEach executes only once javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using a forEach method to add an event listener to each button, everything is working the first time, the function is calling the **filterElements** function as wanted BUT when i try to click **a second time** the code doesen't respond, could it be because of my HTML collection that I am transforming to an Array using **Array.from** or what could it be ?

```
function filterPhotograpsIndividualTages(dataJson) {
  
    const individualTags = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('individual-tags'));
    individualTags.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', () => {   //this is the forEach method
       
        /*onClick clear the old HTML of photographersDiv and call
         the function filterElements to execute his block code!*/
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = "";                                       
        filterElements(dataJson, btn);// function is invoked here
  })) 
};

// this function is being called inside of the filterPhotograpsIndividualTages function
function filterElements(dataJson, btn){ 

    dataJson.photographers.forEach(photographe => {

        if(photographe.tags.indexOf(btn.id) != -1) {

            const photographersDiv = document.getElementById('container');
            const div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = `
                <div class="photographerContainer">
                    <a href="photographers.html?id=${photographe.id}">
                        <div class="portraitBox">
                            <img src="${photographe.portrait}" alt="photo">
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="name">${photographe.name}</h1>
                    </a>
                    <p class="city">${photographe.city}, ${photographe.country}</p>
                    <p class="tagline">${photographe.tagline}</p>
                    <p class="price">${photographe.price}€/jour</p>
                    <p class="tags">${photographe.tags.map(tag => `<button id=${tag} class="tag individual-tags">#${tag}</button>`).join(" ")}</p>  
                </div>
            `  
            photographersDiv.appendChild(div);
        }})
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add event like this, it only binding to DOM you have selected with getElementsByClassName not with the one re-add after delete

Instead you should bind whole document and check event's target

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('your_class')) {
        Function();
    }
});
```